# Content Provider INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER (installing content provider as a separate apk)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, apk

I have two applications which use the same content provider, but I can't put the same content provider in both applications- it shows INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error. So I have put my content provider in a 3rd .apk and used this from two applications and it is working well.

Now the problem is- The content provider apk must be installed before any of those two apps can be installed on the device. Otherwise, it shows Provider not found error during installation.

So, how can I ensure that the provider apk is installed before any of the other apks is installed?

Is there a way to merge the content provider apk with both of the other apks separately, so they will be installed together as two applications and won't show INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error?

I need to merge the content provider apk with both applications, because the user may not install both applications or may install them both on a single device.

Comment: This is a very interesting problem. A similar one explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578751/conflicting-content-providers. I'm not sure if there's an answer in there for you thats why I added it as a comment. This reminds me of the problem that you get in C/C++ with header files, and why you use #ifndef/#define

Comment: @James thanks for your response. I thought of the solution provided in the topic you mentioned, but I am seeking for something better. Putting the provider in a separate apk and installing it first solves the error INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER and I think is better than keeping two providers. But I need to ensure that the provider apk is installed first or somehow merge the apks as I mentioned.

Comment: See also a comprehensive answer by @CommonsWare http://stackoverflow.com/a/10791144/94363

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution i can think of is, make content provider part of both the applications with different packageid's internally.and export it using android:exported = true.  Both might be using the same code though.

At the start of the application you check if the other content provider exists on the device if it's there you start using it,otherwise you fallback to local content provider. when the other applicaton installs it can does the same check.

To protect your cotent provider from everyone else, you can define a custom permission to protect it, so that your applications can only use it or you can also put some custom authentication like some secret key to access the content provider. you can have this authentication code in all methods of content provider.

Comment: It seems a possible solution, but not what I expect. Maybe there is no way to package two apks as one in android.

Answer (score 37):

You can solve it by changing the value of `android:authorities` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. The reason for the error is that another application installed on your device already uses that same value for `android:authorities`.

Answer (score 9):

To solve this error: **`Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER`**

change the value of **`android:authorities`** in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file another application installed on your device already uses that same value for android:authorities.

Answer (score 2):

You use one unic data like Facebook API registration numer or something like it in your manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) for both programs: for which already installed and for that you try and cant install. You need:

1. Try to find something like this and check is it for your current
   program:

> android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider23473465463573466" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true"/>

2. Check if is not dublicate in another programs if it is for
   program you trying to install.

Answer (score 0):

It means your phone already has provider with same authorities, registered by different application(could be your other example).Change your provider authorities i.e. `android:authorities` and your are good to go.