# Getting INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER when using a library. Can ContentProvider be registered dynamically?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Content Provider INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER (installing content provider as a separate apk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273592/content-provider-install-failed-conflicting-provider-installing-content-provide)

The Problem :

We have a library that uses a `ContentProvider`.  It therefore has relevant methods to use and create the `ContentProvider`.  When we build app A with this `ContentProvider` declared for an authority, all works well.

A second application that intends to use the same `ContentProvider` cannot be installed after this, without throwing the `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER` error.  The only option is to declare the `ContentProvider` with a new Authority, which is not what we want ( as the requirement is to use any existing `ContentProvider` already defined for that Authority).

Is it therefore possible to :

1) Register a `ContentProvider` programmatically (i.e. if `ContentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient` returns null, can a `ContentProvider` be registered in the app?)

OR

2) Specify in the manifest the `ContentProvider` needs to be registered only if the desired authority does not already exist?

Comment: This is almost similar problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273592/content-provider-install-failed-conflicting-provider-installing-content-provide