# Find all the music as a list which are not in a playlist in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, playlist, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I want to get all the musics which are not in a given playlist using CursorLoader. Is it possible?

We can get all the music in a list using the following code

```
loader = new CursorLoader(context, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members
                .getContentUri("external", playlistID), proj,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0 ", null, ORDER_BY);
```

But I need to do the opposite, which is to get all the music that are not in a given playlist. How can I do that?

Comment: I think something should work as a selectionArgs

Comment: Is there a way for subtracting the content of a cursor from another cursor? Like allSongsCursor - singlePlaylistCursor.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you fix your `LowAcceptRateException` - that's a critical failure around here that's likely to interfere with questions being answered in the long run - but if you do not mind doing stuff that is hard to maintain and abuses internal functionality in the `MediaProvider` you can do like this to get songs that are *not* in a (specific) playlist.

```
loader = new CursorLoader(context, Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,
            Media._ID + " NOT IN (SELECT audio_id FROM audio_playlists_map WHERE playlist_id=?) AND " + 
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0 ", 
            new String[]{String.valueOf(playlistID}, ORDER_BY);
```

**Edit:** Corrected `audio_playlist_map` to `audio_playlists_map`

Comment: Thanks! Where do I find that audio_playlist_map table?

Comment: Receiving error ---05-22 18:36:37.161: E/DatabaseUtils(513): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: audio_playlist_map: , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, _data, _display_name, album, artist, composer, year, album_id, _size FROM audio WHERE (_id NOT IN (SELECT audio_id FROM audio_playlist_map WHERE playlist_id=?) AND is_music != 0 ) ORDER BY title COLLATE NOCASE ASC

Comment: Oh right, yeah, it's probably called `audio_playlists_map` actually. Missed an `s`. That's what happens when you write SQL from memory.

Comment: Hey Jens! Would you please take a look at my question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273592/content-provider-install-failed-conflicting-provider-installing-content-provide

Comment: Either use a *different authority* for each of the providers and detect the presence when installing the second app - and adjust the authority in the `Uri`s you use to call the ContentProvider - i.e. "user installs App1, App1 does not detect App2 and configures itself to use authority #1 in all subsequent calls" - then "user installs App2, App2 finds App1 and configures itself to use authority #1 in all subsequent calls" - i.e. make the `Uri`s variable. This poses a problem when the user uninstalls `App1` however - his data will be lost in `App2` also.

Comment: But it works well if I install the provider as a different apk! Is there no way to supply 2 apks as one or in a single package in Android Market?

Comment: Nope not that I know of - short of launching Google Play/Market & requesting that the user installs your other "provider" app if it's missing.